# Scoreboard from MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database with two tables. One holds item data, and one holds price statistics for the items in the other table.

Item Table
itemid (int, auto increment) | name (varchar) | description (varchar) | added_on (datetime)

stats table:
id (int, auto increment) | item (int) | price (int) | date_seen ( datetime )

The 'itemid' column in the first table is unique and is referenced as 'item' in the second table Each time the price gets checked for an item, its added to the stats table if the prioce changed from the last time it'd been checked

As an example, the tables look like this:

```
Item Table
itemid (int, auto increment) | name (varchar) | description (varchar) | added_on (datetime)
1  | testproduct1 | This is a testproduct | 2020-04-23 16:43:47
2  | testproduct2 | This is a testproduct too | 2020-04-23 17:08:32
```

```
stats table:
id (int, auto increment) | item (int) | price (int) | date_seen ( datetime )
1 | 1 | 7 | 2020-04-23 09:12:00
2 | 1 | 4 | 2020-04-23 09:34:00
3 | 2 | 8 | 2020-04-23 09:12:00
4 | 2 | 6 | 2020-04-23 09:34:00
5 | 1 | 3 | 2020-04-23 10:08:00
6 | 2 | 4 | 2020-04-23 10:08:00
```

Lets say I'd like to get a Top5 of Items added today, sorted by the last_seen DESC, and then sorted by price DESC, so you would get the following output:

```
NAME          |PRICE| date_seen
 testproduct2 | 4   | 2020-04-23 10:08:00
 testproduct1 | 3   | 2020-04-23 10:08:00
```

How would I go about that? I tried the following

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
    i.itemid,
    i.name,
    s.price,
    s.date_seen AS sdate,
FROM
   items i
INNER JOIN stats s
    ON i.itemid = s.item
WHERE i.added_on LIKE '2020-04-23%'
) AS sub  
ORDER BY `sub`.`sdate`  DESC,`sub`.`price` DESC
GROUP BY i.itemid
```

However, the group by doesnt seem to be allowed here, without it, the query works and I am getting results sorted by date, but the price isnt sorted at all. What would be the correct query to get the desired result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please learn how to use proper `GROUP BY`.  What's the point of `GROUP BY` without aggregation?  `SELECT * ... GROUP BY` should not have run because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to filter on the latest `stats` record per item:

```
select i.name, s.price, s.date_seen
from item i
inner join stats s on s.item = i.itemid
where s.date_seen = (
    select max(s1.date_seen) 
    from stats s1 
    where 
        s1.date_seen >= '2020-04-23' 
        and s1.date_seen < '2020-04-24' 
        and s1.item = s.item
)
order by s.date_seen desc, s.price
```

Note that I changed the predicates on the date: no function comes into play, so it may take advantage of an index.

Comment: Thank you for this query. When testing mysql returns a 504 rejected after some time, so I'll be going to troubleshoot that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You had a comma in the inner selct at the end ´, that was to much

and GROUP By has to come **before** THE ORDER BY

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
    i.itemid,
    i.name,
    s.price,
    s.date_seen AS sdate
FROM
   items i
INNER JOIN stats s
    ON i.itemid = s.item
WHERE i.added_on LIKE '2020-04-23%'
) AS sub  
GROUP BY itemid
ORDER BY `sub`.`sdate`  DESC,`sub`.`price` DESC
```

To get the last date and the price you have to get the right stats line with a subquery.

```
SELECT
    i.itemid,
    i.name,
    s.price,
    s.date_seen AS sdate
FROM
   items i
INNER JOIN stats s
    ON i.itemid = s.item
WHERE s.date_seen = (SELECT MAX(date_seen) 
FROM stats WHERE date_seen <= i.added_on and s.item = i.itemid)
```

There are more than one way to do things.

```
SELECT
    i.itemid,
    i.name,
    s.price,
    s.date_seen AS sdate
FROM
   items i
INNER JOIN stats s
    ON i.itemid = s.item
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(date_seen) maxdate,item FROM stats GROUP BY item) s1 ON s1.item = s.item AND s.date_seen = s1.maxdate;
```

See new example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/3

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just made the required changes, but it now seems to grab the first price it finds, those from 2020-04-23 09:12:00, instead of the ones from 2020-04-23 10:08:00 . Thats why I thought I would order by (so i'd have the latest date/time and then group by to hopefully only get the latest available data per item. What changes do I need to make to this query, to make it return the latest price-data per item?

Comment: Somehow this query also triggers a 504 rejected (Just like the query that GMB provided. )I'm going to do som e troubleshooting on that. But thanks again for your help!

Comment: please check the linked fiddle and see if you can reproduce and also write the **complete** error message

Comment: The fiddle works, even though it doesnt sort high price to low. But when using the query it just never returns. Thats where the 504 came from in PHPMyAdmin. Running the query directly on the MySQL CLI, never returns, it just hangs. The dataset isnt that big, both tables contain between 80.000 and 100.000 records.

Comment: as i said the **complete error message** please., that is vital. I checlked but it also works with older mysql versions.

Comment: It (PHPMyAdmin) says that the connection to the server was lost, but I guess that that's just another way of saying that the server didnt return anything in time, since the query keeps running endlessloy when executed on the Mysql CLI.

Comment: I changed it a bit, does the same.result.  in workbench i would increase the timeout to see what happens